# How is a label in between `else-if` allowed?

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, visual-c++, label

Here is a simple example (not tied to specific platform):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        if(i == 0) printf("1\n");
        else if (i == 1) goto checkfor2;
        else checkfor2: if(i == 2 || i == 1) printf("2\n");
}
```

Live [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n8hJSHpXcYARb3iq).

My original Windows code from which this question raised:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
main() //sample with Win32 API
{
    for (;;) //infinite loop for my main logic
        if (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 1) != WAIT_TIMEOUT, true) //#1 check for some event
            //oops set comma true to test this event code
        {
            //do something
            //but here it will loop infinte and wouldn't check for #3
            //so if something goes wrong I can't exit

            //so clever me did the following:

            goto checkforexit; //see label on #3 below
        }
        else if (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent2, 1) != WAIT_TIMEOUT) //#2 check for another event
        {
            //do something else
        }
        else checkforexit: /*wow in between else and if*/ if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BACK) & 0x8000 && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) //#3 check for keyboard shortcut for exit
            exit(0); //termination code
}
```

I was surprised that this worked - it seems both the original `else if` and the label to the `if` are working as intended - how is this possible?

I would appreciate if you add a quote to the C standard.

It's working both on gcc (as tested on wandbox) and MSVC.

Comment: The `if` statement is `if ( expression ) statement` ([C11 6.8.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.1)). The statement part of the if can be a labeled statement ([C11 6.8.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.1)) which is a statement in its own right. `if (1) foo: puts("foo"); else bar: puts("bar");`

Comment: The `else if() ...` can be `else { if() ... }`

Comment: @pmg For some weird reason I had engraved in my mind `else if` being its own statement. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

The label is actually part of the `if` statement; the `if` statement is labeled.

C 2018 6.8 defines a *statement* (a token in the formal grammar for the C language) to be one of:

- *labeled-statement*
- *compound-statement*
- *expression-statement*
- *selection-statement*
- *iteration-statement*
- *jump-statement*

An `if … else` statement is defined in 6.8.4 to be one of the options for a *selection-statement*:

- `if` `(` *expression* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*

As you can see, what comes after the `else` is a *statement*, and a *statement* can be a *labeled-statement*, one form of which is “*identifier* `:` *statement*”. (The other forms use the `case` and `default` labels for a `switch` statement.)

This is not an impediment to the compiler because it simply includes the transfer of control from a `goto` statement to the label as part of its control-flow graph, which already includes jumps such as from the `if` to the `else` (since the first *statement* is skipped if the *expression* is false), from the end of a `while` loops to the beginning, from a `break` statement to outside a `for` statement, and even from `goto` statements to labels inside `while` or `for` loops. By constructing a general control-flow graph, the compiler is able to handle arbitrary control flow and does not care about “structured programming.” Structured programming is a tool to aid humans, but software can handle arbitrary cases without that tool.

You can largely use labels to jump around arbitrarily inside a function, but a problem occurs when you jump into a scope in which a variable length array or other variably modified type is declared. The C standard does not define the behavior if you do this, such as:

```
if (flag)
    goto label;
while (foo)
{
    int bar[n];
    label: // Error, delaration of `bar` is skipped.
    …
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The formal syntax of a label can be found at C11 6.8.1:

> *labeled-statement:*
> *identifier* `:` *statement*

Where *statement* can be one of:

> *statement:*
> *labeled-statement*
> *compound-statement*
> *expression-statement*
> *selection-statement*
> *iteration-statement*
> *jump-statement*

`if` is a selection statement, so code like `my_label : if(something) ;` is perfectly fine syntax-wise.

As for "else if", it actually isn't a statement syntax item of its own (this is a common misunderstanding) - it is just an `else` containing a nested `if` written on the same line. But we like to write them together style-wise to improve readability. To clarify the indention, your code could also have been written like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        if(i == 0) 
            printf("1\n");
        else 
            if (i == 1) 
                goto checkfor2;
        else 
            checkfor2: if(i == 2 || i == 1) 
                printf("2\n");
}
```

Where `checkfor2: if` is valid, as per the previously quoted syntax.